# Can't Find Package (Pechkin) in Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have some problem with Visual studio Nuget.

I want to use `Pechkin` in my web project , but I cant find this package in Visual Studio Nuget Maneger.

I thought this have been remove , but it can be find on Nuget web.[NuGet - Pechkin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pechkin/)

Is my Visual Studio NuGet have some problem ? or I got some wrong step on this ?

How can I find `Pechkin` in my Nuget ?

[image]

(Can't found `Pechkin 0.5.8.1` , `Pechkin.Synchronized` in NuGet , Just `TuesPechkin` and some else)

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you are not using the nuget.org package source but a different one which perhaps does not have the Pechkin NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problems with my Visual Studio do add this package. Check out the image:

[image]

I've found the package for a Windows Forms application. What type of application you are using? Maybe this package is not available to the type of application you want. There are packages that are available to a Windows Forms application, but not for a Mobile application, for example.

EDIT:

As this library is designed to work with .NET 4.0, you must ensure that your application targets the 4.0 .NET framework.
To check this, right-click on your project and go to Properties. You will see the Target Framework option. Set it to the .NET 4.0 option or above and test again to see if the package appears in NuGET.

Comment: I use Web Form ... Doesn't it support Web Form ? o.O

Comment: But, I creat a new project (Windows Form) to test , It really only can be find in Windows Form project  ... How to solve it ? I need use it in my web form project ...

Comment: The Pechkin NuGet package supports .NET 4.0 so you should be able to use it in a web forms project.

Comment: I got it , You solve my problem , The reason why I can't find package is my web project is .net 3.5 , thank you bro !